# How to use purrr::map2() with inconsistent vector lengths

Tags: r, iteration, purrr

I want to produce summary statistics based on 4 different columns. The different summary statistics are calculated based on a label column (which has two values) and the different group columns (group 1, 2 and 3). Thus, you get different tbls for the Label1*group1, Label1*group2 etc.

```
set.seed(123)
tbl <- tibble(
       label  = rep(c("Label1", "Label2"), 6),
       group1  = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 3),
       group2  = rep(c("x", "y","z"), 4),
       group3  = rep(c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"), 2),
       value1 = rnorm(12, 100, 10),
       value2 = rnorm(12, 50, 5)
)

tbl
```

I made a sample function and I want the function to use the two vectors as the `.x` and the `.y` argument.

```
tmp_label <- c("Label1", "Label2") # .x
group <- c("group1", "group2", "group3") # .y

# .f
tmp_function <- function(Label, group) {

  tbl %>% 
    filter(label %in% tmp_label) %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(value1),
              mean2  = mean(value2)) %>% 
    mutate(Label = tmp_label)

}
```

Thus, I thought using `purrr::map2()` seemed the appriopiate function to get the different summary statistics. However, it produces an error which tells me that the mapped vectors must have consistent lengths. Thus my question is 1) is it possible to use `purrr` functions for inconstistent vector lengths and 2) if not, is there another (preferably tidy) way to get the different summary statistics. The produced error:

```
map2(.x = tmp_label, .y = group, .f = tmp_function)
Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 2
* `.y` has length 3
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @ akrun, thanks for the reply. With respect to the `map2`: i already noticed the fact that it requires consistent vector lengths. However, I'm curious if there is still a way iterate over the tbl in order to get the different summary statistics (preferably with purrr/tidyverse)

Comment: I updated the solution.  I  think you need `crossing`

Comment: @ akrun, I indeed needed crossing. Thanks for the suggestion. I code the code working and accepted your answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can change the `group_by` to `group_by_at` that takes string as input.  Also, based on the description, OP is interested in combinations of 'tmp_label', 'group' vectors.  We can use `crossing` to create all the combinations and pass that in `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
tmp_function <- function(Label, group) {
  tbl %>% 
     filter(label %in% Label) %>%  # changed the tmp_label to  Label
     group_by_at(group) %>% 
      summarise(mean = mean(value1),
          mean2  = mean(value2)) %>% 
     mutate(Label = Label)
}

d1 <- crossing(tmp_label, group) 
map2(d1$tmp_label, d1$group, tmp_function)
```